# How to reduce scope of subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I've got SQL running on MS SQL Server similar to the following:

```
SELECT
    CustNum,
    Name,
FROM
    Cust
    LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 
    CustNum, MAX(OrderDate) as LastOrderDate
        FROM
            Orders
        GROUP BY 
            CustNum) as Orders 
    ON Orders.CustNum = Cust.CustNum
WHERE
    Region = 1
```

It contains a subquery to find the MAX record from a child table. The concern is that these tables have a very large number of rows. It seems like the subquery would operate on all the rows of the child table, even though only a very few of them are actually needed because of the WHERE clause on the outer query

Is there a way to reduce the scope of the inner query? Something like adding a WHERE clause to only include the records that are included in the outer query? Something like

```
WHERE CustomerOrders.CustomerNumber = Customers.CustomerNumber -- Customers from the outer query.
```

I suspect that this is not necessary, but I am getting some push back from another developer and I wanted to be sure (my SQL is a little rusty).

Comment: Look at the execution plan. Always look at the execution plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the subquery.  It will have to summarize all the data.  You could re-write the query like this:

```
SELECT CustNum, Name, max(OrderDate) as LastOrderDate
FROM Cust LEFT JOIN
     Orders
     ON Orders.CustNum = Cust.CustNum
WHERE Region = 1
group by CustNum, Name
```

This would let the SQL optimizer choose the optimal path.

If you know that there are very, very few customers matching `Region = 1` and you have an index on `CustNum, OrderDate` in `Orders`, you could write the query like this:

```
select CustNum, Name,
       (select top 1 OrderDate
        from Orders o
        where Cust.CustNum = o.CustNum
        order by OrderDate desc
       ) as LastOrderDate
from Cust
Where Region = 1
```

I think you would get a very similar effect by using `cross apply`.

By the way, I'm not a fan of re-writing queries for such purposes.  But, I haven't found a SQL optimizer that would do anything other than summarize all the `orders` rows in this case.

Answer (score 1):

No it's generally not necessary if your statistics etc are up to date.  That's the job of the optimiser.  You can try the CROSS APPLY operator if you think you're missing out on some shortcuts but generally if you have all constraints and stats it will be fine.

Your proposed additional WHERE might make sense to you, but as it doesn't correlate to anything in the actual query you posted it will change the results (if it works at all).  If you want comments on that you need to post tables & relations etc.

Best way is to check the execution plan and see if it's doing anything dumb.